# $f_1:\left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right), f_1(x)=\left(\frac{\ln\left(\cos^2(x)\right)}{\ln\left(x^3\right)}\right)$

Tags: analysis, continuity

let $f_1:\left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right),  f_1(x)=\left(\frac{\ln\left(\cos^2(x)\right)}{\ln\left(x^3\right)}\right)$

$\rightarrow$ The ln function is only used for an interval with positive values so I assume it is continuous.

$$|f(x) - f(x_0)|$$
$$\left|\frac{\ln\left(\cos^2(x)\right)}{\ln\left(x^3\right)}- \frac{\ln\left(\cos^2(x_0)\right)}{\ln\left(x_0^3\right)}\right|$$

**Question**: How can I go on to get $|x-x_0|$ to have my $\delta$ and finally to define the $\epsilon$.

I appreciate every hint.

[image]

Comment: The domain is $(0,1)\cup(1,\frac \pi 2$

Comment: Please tell me you did not "cancel" the symbols $\frac{\ln}{\ln}$ in the fraction going from the 2nd to the 3rd displayed expression. That's certainly not a legal step in simplifying an expression!

Comment: Also notice your $f_1$ became $f$. I would suggest dropping the subscript altogether, it is meaningless here.